# Image icon in expandable list view in android

Tags: java, android

I want to add an image icon in expandable list view .I have seen the tutorial they have added only in child elements .Is there any other way to add image icon in parent 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the `setGroupIndicator(Drawable)` method of ExpandableListView.

Comment: Hi,
    This method adds the icon to all the parent but if i want to add seperate icon for each parent respectively .Is it possible.

Comment: If you want to really customize your group layout, why don't you try using or subclassing SimpleExpandableListAdapter? Set custom resource for expandedGroupLayout, and load the image you need on getGroupView(int, boolean, View, ViewGroup). Good luck and comment back when you see/try it.

Answer (score 13):

You can also define your own groupIndicator in XML:

First define your own drawable (I called it list_view_group_indicator.xml and placed it in the drawable directory)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_expanded="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/packagexgeneric" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/packagexgenericclose" />
</selector>
```

Then use it as a drawable for your expandableListview

```
<ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/server_show_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:groupIndicator="@drawable/list_view_group_indicator" />
```

Answer (score 1):

ok

```
   public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

    if(getChildrenCount(groupPosition)==0)
    {
          // how do i hide the group indicator ?

    }
```

So, how can modify the group indicator for empty groups ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    indicator=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_img);
    if ( getChildrenCount( groupPosition ) == 0 ) {
        indicator.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
    }
    else {
        indicator.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
        indicator.setImageResource( isExpanded ? 
       R.drawable.ic_arrow_up : R.drawable.ic_arrow_down );
    }
```