# removing parent icon in expandable list

Tags: android

I have made an customizable expandable List. Where I can customize the child. But in parent(Group ID), I want to change the default icon of the parent which look like.

Can   anyone  help  me?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is answered on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355771/image-icon-in-expandable-list-view-in-android).

In short, the `setGroupIndicator(Drawable)` method of [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

Comment: I  have    use    simpleExpandableList   group adapter.So   how   can I  do it  programitically whithout   using xml.

Comment: Look, if you show me code I'll be happy to fix it to do what you want. Otherwise, I've given about the best answer I can.